# Animate element from margin:auto .

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple `div` element and I use CSS animations to create a smooth layout:

```
div{
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Although is quite simple to animate the element using pixel specific ratios http://jsfiddle.net/yBJ42/1/
it fails when the element is center with `margin:0 auto` 
Is there any way to fix that behavior? Unfortunately I can't use absolute positioned elements as the main container in my layout uses CSS calc in order to calculate it's width and I want to keep `margin-right:0` as a sidebar is revealed.

Furthermore calculating and adapting containers width and margin using JavaScript is not the my preferable way of handling this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you wanna use jQuery or just plain CSS? for the animation I mean

Comment: @Amin Jafari I have no problem on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the jQuery version of what you want: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yBJ42/16/)**

```
var centerMargin=($(window).width()/2)-($('div').width()/2)+'px';
$('div').css('margin-left',centerMargin);
var toggled=false;
$(".animate").click(function(){
    if(!toggled){
        $('div').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},1000);
        toggled=true;
        }
    else{
        $('div').animate({marginLeft:centerMargin},1000);
        toggled=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about applying CSS transformations? You can use `transform: translateX` to move your element on the X-axis without impacting your `margin: 0 auto`

For example, move your element 100% to the left of the current position. (100% is equal to the width of the transformed element)

```
-ms-transform: translateX(-100%)
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%)
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%)
transform: translateX(-100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not animate properties between 2 non numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this to/from properties like auto, inherit etc. You need to set explicit values  in px, percentage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The transform suggestion is a solid solution (see Mike Vranchx's answer).

However, if you absolutely must use margin: auto, than the only way to animate it is to use a nested div. The outer div handles the centering, while animation is handled on the inner div.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```